# NodeJs Cassandra driver is getting stuck

Tags: javascript, node.js, cassandra, datastax, aws-lambda

I am trying to connect to a Cassandra cluster in NodeJs but when I execute a query, prepared or not, it just gets stuck. The callback isn't called at all and the process is just hanging. What could cause this? I am able to connect using devcenter using the same host/keyspace.

```
var Cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
var cassandraClient = new Cassandra.Client({ contactPoints:['*.*.*.*'], keyspace: '*'});

cassandraClient.on('log', function(level, className, message,     furtherInfo) {
    console.log('log event: %s -- %s', level, message);
});

cassandraClient.connect(function (err) {
  console.log(err)
});

console.log("Starting C* getting data");

cassandraClient.execute(query, params, {prepare: true}, function(err,  result) {

  if(err) console.log(err);
  res = result;
  console.log("Done C*");
  console.log('result: ' + result.rows[0]);
  notDone = false;
});
```

Output:

```
Init Get IP Info
log event: info -- Adding host *.*.*.*:9042
Starting C* getting data
```

And it gets stuck there. Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Where is the Cassandra cluster running? Does your Lambda function have access to the cluster? It sounds like a networking issue.

Comment: From your code, `connect()` and `execute()` are going to be called in parallel, is that what you wanted? It looks like you are dealing with method calls like they were synchronous. In your case, `console.log("Starting C* getting data");` will be called before the client is connected.

Comment: Also, have you tried with a simple query to narrow down the issue, something like `client.execute('SELECT * FROM system.local', callback)`

Comment: Turns out the callback wasn't getting called. Not just for Cassandra driver. fixed it now. Thanks.

Comment: How did you fix this issue?